# How to remove last result from a foreach() result

Tags: php, json

I have some PHP code that grabs data from JSON. The code retruns all the usernames, including the current username to display. My question is, how would I only allow it so that it only shows the recent usernames and not the current?

I am using the Minecraft API for this and the JSON code I am getting can be found [here.](https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/360d11df2b1d41a78e1775df49444128/names)

> Note that `_scrunch` is the current username.

Here's my code that displays the names:

```
// Save the uuid
$uuid = $json->id;

// Get the history (using $json->uuid)
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/' . urlencode($uuid) . '/names');

// Decode it
$json = json_decode($content);

$names = array(); // Create a new array

foreach ($json as $name) {
    $input = $name->name;

    if (!empty($name->changedToAt)) {
        // Convert to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
        //do

       // $input .= ' (changed at ' . $time . ')';
    }

    $names[] = $input; // Add each "name" value to our array "names"

}
```

and to display it

```
<?php echo implode(', ', $names) ;?>
```

Any help would be great! Thanks!

Comment: You can remove last element after your foreloop ends

Comment: You can use [`array_pop()`](http://php.net/array_pop) before the foreach loop, to remove the last name.

Comment: Is current user always last or is it the one with changedToAt?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your loop, just check and exclude if it's the user's name:

```
foreach ($json as $name) {
    $input = $name->name;
    if ($input != _scrunch) {

        if (!empty($name->changedToAt)) {
            // Convert to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
            //do

           // $input .= ' (changed at ' . $time . ')';
        }

        $names[] = $input; // Add each "name" value to our array "names"

    }
}
```

Comment: Ah yes! This seemed to work, easy and simple. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking to remove the last element of the array, array_pop() should do the trick. Then your foreach loop will look over all the elements except the last one.

```
$array = [1, 2, 3]; // sample array
$last = array_pop($array); // remove last element of array and store it into a variable => $array = [1, 2]
// do stuff
foreach($array as $element) {
  ...
}
array_push($array, $last); // push the element to the back of the array => $array = [1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Ah I see, I never knew about `array_pop`! The other answer helped me greatly because I knew what he meant and how to incorporate it, I am fairly knew to PHP! Thanks for the answer, I'm sure many will find it helpful! :)

Comment: Some other very useful functions when working with ordered arrays are array_shift() and array_unshift(). They do the opposite of push and pop, the remove and add to the beginning of array.

Answer (score 0):

Simply count the amount of data returned in the array through the `count` function, and then rank each item within the foreach loop by doing `$foo ++;`

```
// Save the uuid
$uuid = $json->id;

// Get the history (using $json->uuid)
$content = file_get_contents('https://api.mojang.com/user/profiles/' . urlencode($uuid) . '/names');

// Decode it
$json = json_decode($content);
$total = count($json); // This counts the amount of items returned
$rank = 0; // Declaring the rank for future use in the foreach loop
$names = array(); // Create a new array

foreach ($json as $name) {
    $rank ++;
    $input = $name->name;
    if ($rank == $total){
    // Do something if this is the last row

    }
    if (!empty($name->changedToAt)) {
        // Convert to YYYY-MM-DD HH:MM:SS format
        //do

       // $input .= ' (changed at ' . $time . ')';
    }

    $names[] = $input; // Add each "name" value to our array "names"

}
```